# I can not get content from specific url

Tags: php, curl

i have one php file and i want to **scrape** specific element from the url below, but i have problem in my first step. you can see my code below and you can run it to see the content is wrong:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url ="https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Rasht/forecasts/latest";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html_content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html_content;
?>
```

i have this code and when i opened that url with my chrome browser , it's working. but when i want to get content from my php file , wrong page has been get.

Comment: What do you get instead of what?

Comment: Try and specify a User-Agent with your request. That page probably doesn’t want you to steal their data (or do you actually have explicit permission for this?), and therefor likely has measures in place to try and detect requests that are not coming from “normal browsers”.

Comment: Maybe the originator of the site doesn't want it to be scrapped and took precautions? Maybe there are redirects, or Javascript involved?

Comment: @LajosArpad I get "no such path" from weather-forcast instead of when i open that exact link in chrome the path existed and has contents about weahter information

Comment: The minimum would be: Ask the company if you're allowed to grab & use THEIR content on YOUR site... If they allow it, you may ask for an API or a "good" way to get the information. Be prepared to pay for their service...

Comment: It seems that the header you send via cURL differs from the header your browser sends, but you should first check whether what you are doing is both morally and legally okay.

Comment: @MohammadKiyan Please edit clarifying details into your question; do not use the comments for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php, there are plenty of options that you can use with curl, by playing a bit the following code can work with your url.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.weather-forecast.com/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $data;
```

and `$data` variable has whole page's html.

you can try parsing the data from the page by utilizing php [DOM Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and convert them to the data type you want (object class, array etc).